# html5 <select> element offset issue on Mac

Tags: html, css, dropdown, html-select

I have that problem on my macbook which doesn't happen on a windows computer even though I use the same browser (Chrome) with both computers.

The options of the  element offsets and appears on the element's side instead of opening normally at it's bottom side.

Does anyone know that problem?

thanks.

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 right">
        <select class="my-select" ng-model="chosenContact" ng-options="contact.name for contact in contacts">
            <option value="" class="my-select" disabled="true">-choose-</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-select{
margin-left: 10px;
width: 100%;
height: 30px;

direction: rtl;

text-align: center;
font-size: 13.4px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #555;

background-color: #fff;
background-image: none;

border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;

box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
outline: none;

transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
```

}

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mItr4.png)

Comment: try adding cursor:pointer; to that class..

Answer (score 0):

It's the `direction: rtl` property that is causing your issue (I don't have this issue in Safari or Firefox Mac btw, displays correctly). This may be a Chrome bug?

Comment: thanks for the comment, but what if i need the text inside the element to has a rtl direction? 
text-align: right; doesn't fix that

Comment: As much as I'm loathe to say it can't be done in CSS, this might be a javascript job, potentially using something like Select2 (https://select2.github.io) as I don't recall being able to style Option elements for Selects on Mac with CSS.